# How do I evaluate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\sqrt[n]{(x+1)(x+3)\dots(x+2n-1)}-x-n)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\sqrt[n]{(x+1)(x+3)\dots(x+2n-1)}-x-n)$

After inspecting the limits computed by Wolfram Alpha for various values of $n$, I was able to infer that the limit is:

$-\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(k)(k+1)}{2}}{n}= \dfrac{1-n^{2}}{6}$.

However, after trying several methods, I am at a complete loss for a way to prove this limit with steps. Can anyone offer an insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\sqrt[n]{(x+1)(x+3)\dots(x+2n-1)}=x\left(1+\frac{A_n}{x}+\frac{B_n}{x^2}+O(1/x^3)\right)^{1/n}.$$
where $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)=n^2$ and 
$$B_n=\sum_{1\leq k<j\leq n}(2k-1)(2j-1)=\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)^2(2j-1).$$

Now use the fact that as $t\to 0$,
$$(1+t)^{1/n}=1+\frac{t}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right)t^2+O(t^3).$$
Hence
$$\sqrt[n]{(x+1)(x+3)\dots(x+2n-1)}=x+n+\left(\frac{B_n}{n}-\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}\right)\frac{1}{x}+O(1/x^2)$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\sqrt[n]{(x+1)(x+3)\dots(x+2n-1)}-x-n)=
\frac{B_n}{n}-\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}.$$